# Is there any way to receive a qualifier in a @Bean method?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have an interface of `TokenProvider` and another of `TokenManager`:

```
interface TokenProvider {
    fun generateToken(): TokenData
}

interface TokenManager {
    fun getToken(): String
}
```

Depending on my environment, I would like to use a different `TokenManager`, like `CachingTokenManager`(for development/production) and a `NotCachingTokenManager`(for test), and depending on the operation, I want to use a different `TokenProvider` for a different service(some fake examples: `FacebookTokenProvider`, `GoogleTokenProvider`, `TwitterTokenProvider`, etc)

I already added `@Qualifier(qualifierName)` to the `TokenProvider`, now I would like to know if there is any way to do something like that on Spring:

```
@Configuration
class TokenManagerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("!test")
    fun tokenManager(qualifierName: String): TokenManager = 
        CachingTokenManager(getProviderWith(qualifierName))

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    fun testTokenManager(qualifierName: String): TokenManager = 
        NotCachingTokenManager(getProviderWith(qualifierName))

    private fun getProviderWith(qualifierName: String) = // logic for finding correct TokenProvider
}
```

Is there any way to do that? I don't want to write a `TokenManager` factory for each qualifier or to to make the Provider take care of the caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask SpringBoot to inject `TokenProvider` for given qualifier.

```
 @Bean
 @Profile("!test")
 fun tokenManager(@Qualifier("qualifierName") TokenProvider provider): TokenManager = 
        CachingTokenManager(provider)
```

Comment: But then I would have to have a factory from each qualifier, no? Like `facebookTokenManager`, `googleTokenManager`, `twitterTokenManager`, etc...

My idea would be to have a @Bean that would create a different `TokenManager` for any asked qualifiers without having to create a method to each one

Comment: `@Bean` denotes single instance being created, Spring will not call this method twice. Moreover, if it is not marked `@Lazy` then Spring is free to instantiate it even before it is being injected somewhere, i.e dynamic qualifier could not be known at this point. I think you should check what Spring `BeanFactory` and/or `BeanResolver` can do for you. However, I feel you are overcomplicating your application.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, a `@Factory` or something like that would make more sense.

But I dunno, to me it makes some sense to Spring to have this feature baked in. It can help autowire things on a easier way.

But yeah, it seems wither I have to compromise my design, or create a `@Bean` for each case